# Refer to a field name in a collection which has a white space character

Tags: filter, powerapps, powerapps-canvas, powerapps-formula, powerapps-collection

I have a collection "Accounts". In that, we have a field which is "Full Name".How to refer to this field in a filter function. I used the following formula:

```
Filter(Accounts,'Full Name' in TextInput2.Text)
```

Here TextInput2.Text is a text input. When I apply this formula,it says 'Full Name' is not recognized.

I expected it to filter by using the 'Full Name' field name.But its saying name not recognized.

Comment: I think you have the field and textinput the wrong way round.
Shouldn't it be:

Filter(Accounts,TextInput2.Text in 'Full Name')

Comment: Surprisingly, this formula works in items property of the DataTable but not on onSelect property of a button or OnChange property of a text input.